# Как при нажатии на график сделать так,чтобы выбиралась ближайшая существующая точка

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

Есть график в матплотлибе,построенный по данным, считанным из эксель файла через пандас,график представляет собой точки по двум столбцам из эксель файла,необходимо сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на любое место на графике выделялась ближайшая лежащая к этому месту существующая точка

Comment: На чистом матплотлибе не получится. Вот вам 5 интерактивных библиотек https://mode.com/blog/python-interactive-plot-libraries/ Ну или PyQt какой-нибудь.

Comment: @CrazyElf можно интерактивно в матплот, мой ответ ниже -> https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/event_handling.html

Comment: @Acinit О, не знал, что у матплотлиба есть интерактивность, хорошо

Answer (score 4):

Я нашёл решение, только оно немного некрасивое, чтоли...

Нам нужно найти ближайшую точку массива от точки нажатия на график, можем создадть функцию используя `numpy`, скормим ей листы `x` и `y` и точки нажатия как `x_val` и `y_val`. Используя теорему Пифагора (формулу расстония между двумя точками в декартовой системе координат), а именно корень из суммы квадратов разности `x-x_val` и `y-y_val` мы получаем расстония от точки нажатия до точки на графике. Затем возьмём минимальное значение данного расстояния, вернём `x[индекс данного расстояния]` и `y[индекс данного расстояния]`.

```
def find_nearest_point(x, y, x_val, y_val):
    distances = np.sqrt((np.array(x) - x_val) ** 2 + (np.array(y) - y_val) ** 2)
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    return x[index], y[index]
```

Чтобы реализовать клик, используем `mpl_connect` с эвентом `'button_press_event'`, в качестве аргумента зададим функцию `on_click`, в которой мы схватим данные ивента, из них достанем точку нажатия, првоерим, что она в предлелах графика, поулчим нашу минимальную дистанцию, заранее очистим график от других точек, а затем построим точку на основе функции минимальной дистанции по графику, а после отрисуем

```
def on_click(event):
    global selected_point

    if event.inaxes:  # Проверка, что событие произошло в пределах графика
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata  # Получите координаты клика
        x_nearest, y_nearest = find_nearest_point(x_data, y_data, x, y)

        # Удалите старую точку, если она есть
        if selected_point:
            selected_point.remove()

        selected_point, = plt.plot(x_nearest, y_nearest, 'ro')  # Установите новую точку на графике
        plt.draw()  # Перерисуйте график
```

В строке

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
```

Можем протестировать, вот полный код

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Создайте пустой список для хранения выбранных точек
selected_point = None

# Примерные данные для графика
x_data = range(1,100)
y_data = range(1,100)

# Создайте функцию для поиска ближайшей точки на линии графика
def find_nearest_point(x, y, x_val, y_val):
    distances = np.sqrt((np.array(x) - x_val) ** 2 + (np.array(y) - y_val) ** 2)
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    return x[index], y[index]

# Функция, которая будет вызываться при клике мышью
def on_click(event):
    global selected_point

    if event.inaxes:  # Проверка, что событие произошло в пределах графика
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata  # Получите координаты клика
        x_nearest, y_nearest = find_nearest_point(x_data, y_data, x, y)

        # Удалите старую точку, если она есть
        if selected_point:
            selected_point.remove()

        selected_point, = plt.plot(x_nearest, y_nearest, 'ro')  # Установите новую точку на графике
        plt.draw()  # Перерисуйте график

# Создайте фигуру и оси для вашего графика
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Нарисуйте график
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, linestyle='-', color='black')

# Настройки для осей и заголовка
ax.set_xlabel('X-ось')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-ось')
ax.set_title('Выбор точек на графике')

# Настройте обработчик событий для кликов мышью
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

# Отобразите график
plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за быстрый ответ !
Интересное решение , опробую его обязательно, тогда как опробую дам Вам обратную связь

Comment: @user571264 если данный ответ устроит вас, не забудьте [пометить его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Добро пожаловать на ruSO!